# Spyder Tools menu missing "open command prompt"

Tags: anaconda, spyder

I updated my spyder version to 3.2.3 from 3.1.3 and now I can't find the *"open command prompt"* option under the *"Tools"* menu.

When downgrading back to 3.1.3 it came back, but I prefer to use the updated version.

Any ideas where it is?

Answer (score 8):

(*Spyder developer here*) The *command prompt* was part of our Python console, removed in Spyder **3.2.0**.

To have command prompts after 3.2, you need to install our third-party plugin called [spyder-terminal](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-terminal).

Comment: I tried to install this using pip by typing "pip install spyder-terminal" after activating the relevant anaconda environment and the installation went fine. Now when opening this environment, the keyboard is not working and I can't type anything (the other environments are OK). Did I do something incorrectly?

Comment: Please open a bug in the `spyder-terminal` repo with a screenshot of how things look for you and we'll take a look at it.

Comment: I also find this bug, and i report this bug. But the maintainers told me that they did not have enough human resource to fix it.

Comment: @ZongzeWu You don't really need Anaconda to install `Spyder` or its plugin `spyder-terminal` (just use the classic `pip install spyder spyder-terminal`). In fact, I've just installed this plugin and it's working well as expected.