# How to install Python packages for use with Spyder without Anaconda

Tags: python, pip, spyder

I've been trying to lean Python and trying to find a good Python coding environment. Spyder seemed to be quite powerful. Though I having problems installing non-default packages. I have to install them in the default environment using pip, since I'm using LabVIEW to connect to python and for now LabVIEW only support the default environment path.

In Spyder I have specified the the Python root folder: C:\Users<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32. The user environment Windows key also contains this path.

I continue to get the "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'impedance'" error message. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63109860/how-to-instal-python-packages-for-spyder), this method should work, but no luck so far.

Comment: Spyder is also a python package. I guess you have to install Spyder into every env you use. Single Spyder installed in base env can't work in any env because it has dependencies. You better try PyCharm to work with multiple envs. If you use Anaconda it may be a bad idea to mix conda and pip packages in a single env (especially base env). I suppose LabView uses Windows' path variable to get python location. So just change it to any env you'd like or specifically created to write code for LabView projects.

Comment: Maybe this could help: 

* Using existing environments by changing the default interpreter preference to point to the environment with your specific packages: https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#using-existing-environment
* Using Spyder standalone installation and the default interpreter preference to point to the environment with your specific packages: https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#using-packages-installer