# I can't install or use PyPDF in Spyder

Tags: python, pdf, anaconda, spyder, pypdf

I have copied a program online to merge some PDF files I have. However, Spyder cannot find the module named PyPDF2. How can I get PyPDF2 using Spyder/Anaconda?

Or is there alternative methods to merging pdfs using this software?

For reference this is the code I have used for the program:

```
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger

source_dir = os.getcwd()

merger = PdfFileMerger()

for item in os.listdir(source_dir):
if item.endswith('pdf'):
merger.append(item)
    

merger.write('File location/Merged file name...')

merger.close()
```

Comment: did you install the library?

Comment: Hi Mahrkeenerh, I'm very new to coding so apologies in advance! I use anaconda navigator to search for/install packages. Is that what you mean by the library?

Comment: yes, that's what I meant. What are you using as your IDE? It may have a different interpreter than the one you installed the library for.

Comment: Cool. I use Spyder as my IDE which is an extension from anaconda. I can't find PyPDF2 in the library. However, I have had no problems using other packages that are available on that library such as numpy, pandas, os, matplotlib etc. Not sure how I can get PyPDF2 or another program to merge pdfs. What do you reckon?

Comment: this should help you installing the package: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63109860/how-to-instal-python-packages-for-spyder

Comment: Thanks for that, I had a good look at that and I can pull up the python interpreter but I'm unsure what to make the location? Do I need to download PyPDF2 externally onto my computer first? I am still quite lost sorry.