# Direct evaluation of lambdified sympy expressions

Tags: python, numpy, lambda, sympy

If I want to lambdify a sympy expression containing sympy functions such as Integrate or sqrt, is there any way to do it so that it directly evaluates to a numeric value?

For example, I have the code:

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdify
x=sp.Symbol("x")
y=sp.Symbol("y")
Ix = sp.Integral(sp.sqrt(x)**y, (x, 1, 2))
A = lambdify(y, Ix, modules=['sympy'])
print(A)
print(A(2))
print(A(2).evalf())
```

Obtaining the ouput:

```
<function _lambdifygenerated at 0x00000238E65881F0>
Integral(x**1.0, (x, 1, 2))
1.50000000000000
```

But I would like the evaluation to return the result `1.50000000000000` already at `print(A(2))` without the need to call `.evalf()`.

Please note that using `A = lambdify(y, Ix, modules=['numpy'])` is not possible, I believe, because Integrate is not defined in Numpy.

Also, I would like to avoid evaluating Ix with `.doit()` or similar methods before lambdifying. I suppose this will make the evaluation much slower if the integrated expression is much more complex than `sp.sqrt(x)**y`.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute:

```
A = lambdify(y, Ix)
```

This is going to use Numpy or Scipy if it is installed. With Scipy, the evaluation works fine:

```
A(2)
# out: 1.5
```

Comment: Thank you @Davide_sd ! Could you please copy the code? If I do not mention 'modules=['sympy']' when lambdifying I always get the following error:

  File "C:\Users\.......\untitled0.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(A(2))

  File "<lambdifygenerated-57>", line 4, in _lambdifygenerated
    Integral(x**(y/2), (x, 1, 2)))

NameError: name 'Integral' is not defined

Comment: Do you have scipy installed? Try to execute this: `import scipy;print(scipy.__version__)`

Comment: Yes: IN:
import scipy;print(scipy.__version__) OUT:
1.5.2

Comment: Try updating Scipy, as I have installed version 1.9.3 and everything works fine

Comment: Same error raising with version 1.9.3... Do you import scipy in the example somehow?

Comment: No. Are you using pip or conda? Are you using some virtual environment?

Comment: I tried both and then checked with import scipy;print(scipy.__version__) that it was updated. I am using Spyder (Python 3.8).

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't use Spyder... did you take a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63109860/how-to-instal-python-packages-for-spyder